# Attach a video to an email using AVAssetExportSession

Tags: swift, xcode, avassetexportsession

I'm rather new to programming, I apologize if my code is way off, I'm trying to use AVAssetExportSession to convert an AVAsset (video) into Data so that I can attach it to an email using MFMailComposer. I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out this is done.

I can not figure out how to access the exported file so I don't know what to set the data to before I launch the mailComposer.

Am I close? Any help would be incredibly appreciated! THANKS.

```
func createVideo() {
    let uiImages = self.images
    let settings = CXEImagesToVideo.videoSettings(codec: AVVideoCodecH264, width: (uiImages[0].cgImage?.width)!, height: (uiImages[0].cgImage?.height)!)
    let movieMaker = CXEImagesToVideo(videoSettings: settings)
    movieMaker.createMovieFrom(images: uiImages) { (fileURL:URL) in
        var video = AVAsset(url: fileURL)

        let exportPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("/video.mp4")
        let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: video, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter?.outputURL = exportURL
        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {

                if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
                    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
                    var subject = "Here's your GIF"
                    var body = "<p>Here is your GIF!!</p>"
                    if let emailDescription = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "emailDescription") as? [String : String] {
                        if let theSubject = emailDescription["subject"] {
                            subject = theSubject
                        }
                        if let theBody = emailDescription["body"] {
                            body = theBody
                        }
                    }
                    mail.setSubject(subject)
                    mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)

                    let data = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportURL)
                        mail.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "video/mp4", fileName: "gif.mp4")
                }
            }

        })


    }
}
```

Comment: exportAsynchronously doesn't pass any parameters in the completion handler you need to pass the data but you are passing void to the method addAttachmentData

Comment: If your movie was successfully exported at the `exporter?.outputURL` you need to load the data from that file url and pass that data to the  addAttachmentData  method https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1389970-outputurl

Comment: @LeoDabus I changed the completion handler, that fixed two of the problems. I still cannot figure out how to access the exported video (data). Is there a way to say "Get the contents of the exportURL?"

Comment: `if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: theUnwrappedURL) {`